# Jquery resizing lost cursor

Tags: jquery, resize

I create small resizing box (red dot to resize): http://jsfiddle.net/a66Zc/
This works fine, when i use mouse cursor slowly, but when I use cursor faster my resizing blocking or doesn't work good.
Why?
I'm too fast?:p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like what you have done with the `mouseup`, you should set the `mousemove` on the document..

example at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/a66Zc/1/

Comment: Hi, a had one sub-question yet.
When I using document in mouseup, i had problem with moving elements: http://jsfiddle.net/G5Wzq/3/.
Problem is when I using red dot to resizing, and i drop outside this drop, next I can't move box. You must try my demo to understood.

Answer (score 1):

Because it works when the mouse is over the small box, when you move up or down quickly, your cursor moves quicker than the box, hence the cursor leaves the box and consequently the dragging is no longer active.